# Is this question about shooting video on topic?

Tags: discussion

This question came up and I wasn't sure if it was on topic or not:

> https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19306/how-do-i-record-shoot-a-computer-monitor-with-a-canon-t2i-550d

Currently the title and body of the question do ask about both video and pictures with the banding issue, but originally it didn't mention photos at all(see edit history). It was my suggestion that prompted the edit to cover photography.

I do not know if banding in video is caused by the same issues in photography, I would assume they are very similar if not identical issues. But the question is, if it is an issue in both photography and videography, should the question really be written to address the photography piece?

Comment: Addendum, jrista(mod) has migrated the question to AVP. I think it is still worth discussion if anyone has any points.

Answer (score 2):

When I see questions like this that clearly show that the user is trying to **capture video with a DSLR, I almost always think it will fit better on the AVP site**.

In this case, I saw a potential cross over where photography might have the same reasoning behind the issue, so I suggested the edit to make it about photography. If the question was JUST about videography, and really that is all the OP was concerned with, then I don't think it is on topic, and it would be better at the AVP site.

I think it is on topic if edited to ask about banding in photography. It is off topic if asking about banding in videography specifically.

Comment: Totally agree here, that question was clearly about video processing, and the added reference to still photography was just an ineffectual way to create some kind of tangential relationship with our site. When its that blatant, there shouldn't be any question about where it belongs.

Comment: Until the AVP site matures a lot more in the area of video recording, I think we will keep seeing a trickle of these cross-over questions that try to tie in a photo aspect to what is really a video question. While I can relate to the motive, I have come to accept that such questions are off topic for Photo-SE. We can't be responsible for another site's topic just because we have members who are capable of providing good (often better) answers. In time, as the other sites grow, hopefully those people with the relevant expertise will become members of both sites.